# Fontello is down. Can I use any alternative for it?

Tags: fonts, fontello

From May 23, 2018 I found the fontello.com is down. Can anyone suggest how can I use the SVG font generated from fontello to add more fonts on other online engines?

Answer (score 4):

While it's down, you can run it locally.

Source is available here: https://github.com/fontello/fontello

You will need to install `git` (https://git-scm.com/downloads) & `node` (https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

After that just clone, install and run the project:

```
git clone https://github.com/fontello/fontello
cd fontello
npm install
node server
```

After that just navigate to `localhost:3000` in your browser

EDIT: this won't work on windows, though.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @PragmaticEd for your kindness. But when I start node server, I get :

```
fontello/lib/system/runner.js:118
  async function execute() {
        ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fontello/server.js:12:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

Comment: I failed to mention, that you need linux for this. This project was never tested on windows, as far as i can tell. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [IcoMoon App](https://icomoon.io/app/), it does the same thing in the browser. You can upload the icons or font svg with drag and drop, like fontello.

Select the icons you want to have in a set and click the download button on the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

In case fontello is down - my suggestion for an alternative is to use the following docker image:

https://hub.docker.com/r/avnerner/fontello_server/

```
docker pull avnerner/fontello_server
docker run -it -p  3000:3000 -d avnerner/fontello_server
```